# how to execute hadoop jar from HDFS FileSystem?

Tags: hadoop

I'm always executing job from local File system as following

```
hadoop jar /home/usr/jar/myjar.jar com.test.TestMain
```

How can I execute same command but myjar.jar will be in hdfs ?

Something like

```
hadoop jar hdfs:///home/usr/jar/myjar.jar com.test.TestMain
```

But of course this doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at `bin/hadoop` script for Hadoop, for executing a jar file it uses this condition --

```
elif [ "$COMMAND" = "jar" ] ; then
  CLASS=org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar
```

This says it uses `RunJar` class to execute the jar.
If you see the RunJar class, the arguments supported are --

```
RunJar jarFile [mainClass] args...
```

where, *jarFile* is accessed using the following code inside RunJar Class--

```
int firstArg = 0;
String fileName = args[firstArg++];
File file = new File(fileName);
```

Hence, *fileName* points to *jarFile*, so *fileName* in my view cannot be a HDFS path as seen above, unless you are somehow able to mount the HDFS in your file system, so that it becomes accessible by the java `File` class.

Answer (score 7):

```
hadoop fs -copyToLocal hdfs:///home/usr/jar/myjar.jar /tmp/myjar.jar && hadoop jar /tmp/myjar.jar com.test.TestMain
```

Comment: Nice trick :-), Thanks. Although it may be various problems with it  - download for each execution, cleanup, run multiple aggregations with different parameters...

Comment: Technically the local file does not have to be called myjar.jar. You can generate a temp dir/file name with /dev/urandom (case with different parameters) and delete it immediately (cleanup). Java does not care if the jar does no longer exist. This is a hack, but it can   avoid all the troubles of having hdfs mounted only manually (fstab mount is happening at the boot time, not the case for hdfs - at a much later time and potentially in safe mode).