# How to run a MapReduce JAR file, which is inside HDFS?

Tags: jar, mapreduce

I am trying to run a map-reduce code which is present inside a Hadoop File system. 
The conventional way of running it : 

hadoop jar [path-to-jar-file-in-local] [main-class] [args]...

**[path-to-jar-file-in-local] - My jar file is in HDFS.**

Comment: Any specific reason to keep the jar file in HDFS ?  You can try copyToLocal the jar file and then run with the conventional way.

Comment: Edge Node Access has been disabled by the client, we only have access to Hadoop Environment. No Unix System permissions have been given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333135/how-to-execute-hadoop-jar-from-hdfs-filesystem). All hadoop commands are invoked by the bin/hadoop script. For executing a jar file it uses RunJar class which has following code snippet

```
int firstArg = 0;
String fileName = args[firstArg++];
File file = new File(fileName);
```

where fileName points to jarFile.

Comment: So in my case, there is no way to execute a Map Reduce, present in HDFS?